# Indicator function in math programming

Tags: modeling, integer-programming, indicator-constraints

Let $x$ be an integer variable that takes the values $1$, $2$ or $3$.
Let $y_1$ and $y_2$ be binary variables.

I want to express the two following logical constraints:

if $x=2$ then $y_1=1$
if $x=3$ then $y_2=1$

That's all. I have looked around here but usually the constraints are inequalities or continuous variables.

**Edit:**

I have come up with the following solutions:

$-1y_1=(x-1)(x-3)$
when $x=1 \rightarrow y_1=0$,
when $x=3 \rightarrow y_1=0$,
when $x=2 \rightarrow y_1=1$.

$2y_2=(x-1)(x-2)$
when $x=1 \rightarrow y_2=0$,
when $x=2 \rightarrow y_2=0$,
when $x=3 \rightarrow y_2=1$.

It breaks the linearity, but the constraints are in a Mixed Integer Nonlinear Programming problem.

Could be that a valid solution?

Comment: Your quadratic equality constraints are correct, but you are better off with linear constraints, even if you already have nonlinearity elsewhere in your model.

Comment: Always go for linearizing equations if you can, and start thinking from adding a new binary variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Introduce binary variable $y_0$ and linear constraints:
\begin{align}
y_0 + y_1 + y_2 &= 1\\
1y_0 + 2y_1 + 3y_2 &= x
\end{align}

Equivalently, eliminating $y_0$:
\begin{align}
y_1 + y_2 &\le 1\\
1 + y_1 + 2y_2 &= x
\end{align}

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to help, and welcome to OR StackExchange, @Miquel.  Please mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: By the way, I guess there's no problem in putting together both restrictions in one single restriction, expressed as follows:

$y_0 +y_1+y_2=1$
$1y_0+2y_1+3y_2=x$

$y_1+2y_2-x=-1$

Comment: Those three equality constraints are linearly dependent, and there is no reason to include all three.  For example, the second constraint is just the sum of the other two.

Comment: Sorry, I'm now around here. What I was trying to say is that the first two restrictions can be displayed as just one restriction, the last one. But yes, they are linearly dependent so of course the third can be used instead of the previous two. Thank you!

Comment: You can remove any one of them but not two.